# How to identify a string source using a standalone list of identifiers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a really quick questions about which function I need to use for my current conundrum:

I'm building a tool that automatically identifies a retailer from the first 5 digits of the account number (their "code" so to speak).

To illustrate in account number "1111122222" the "11111" will be the retailer code and the "22222" will be the customer's unique ID.

Each retailer can have several dozen unique codes so I have a separate sheet with a code table in it. (Separated because it will be split off into a standalone workbook later on)

Codes table looks like this:

```
        Bobs Burgers | Johns Chicken | Ali's Shwarma
        12345        | 56784         |77774
        45698        | 33333         |44444
        12398        | 99999         |55555
```

As we receive data in blocks of 20~30 accounts at a time, all I'd like this thing to do check the accounts against the code list and output the name of the retailer. And maybe yell "conflict, abort and run for the border!" if more than one retailer is identified :)

Apologies for the stupid question, but by this point I'm on my ninth cup of coffee and I just can't remember what functions I need to use.

P.S. The reason why I'm making my life difficult and not using a standard lookup table is because higher ups want no manual involvement from the end users with the data, so it's all gotta be identified and forwarded to relevant parties without them touching the data or destinations. I've already got the Importing automated and have the distribution ready to go, just the middle part that sent me for a loop. I'll post the full code of the tool once it's complete in case anyone needs something like this.

Comment: What will be the enter parameter , and what will be the output ?

Enters-> 123457890
->12345 = Account
is it ?

Comment: " no manual involvement from the end users" meaning they can still hit a button?  you can code up your `index/match` or `vlookup` into VBA and provide appropriate outputs.

Comment: Please note, StackOverflow focuses on answering *objective* questions, not subjective questions.  Tips on how to possibly do something fall into the `Too Broad` category and related questions are often Closed.  If you would please edit your post to be more objective, that will most likely get you further on this forum.

Comment: *and forwarded to relevant parties without them touching the data or destinations* - that's what a *report* does: have a sane, normalized data source (column A "AccountNumber", column B "CustomerName"), and use standard lookups - then write a macro that takes the data source and lays it out the way higher-ups and 3rd-parties want to see it.

Comment: @RonanVico Pretty much, data enters as a list of accounts, first 5 digits get compared to the list, output is the header of the list account matched to (which is later used for distribution). So if using the example table I posted it would be Enters -> 4569822222, 1234599786, 1239844444 = Bobs Burgers.

Comment: @Cyril  Again, apologies, I know the question is a bit broader than I'd like but brain farts tend to do that. And yes, they're allowed to press a button. Summarized the process needs to be User opens spreadsheet -> clicks "send" on tool -> Tool identifies Bobs Burgers and sends email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the brain fart - I figured out the solution. I was trying set codes up as a table with the Retailer as the header, with each retailer in their own column. Which just wasn't working in any way. My less than elegant solution was to reformat the codebook as a "code:Retailer" table which allowed a VLookup to actually pull the data proper, and to have the codes extracted via =LEFT(TEXT(cell),5) function inside a hidden buffer sheet in the workbook rather than via VBA.

I then set up a pivot table in the hidden sheet that gave me a nice percentage value to work off of and set up a data refresh gate at every step in the macros.

Whole thing is a bit slow and will require a bit of manual installation on everyone's PCs but it works now.

P.S. Thanks @Cyril for reminding me of Index - made another one of my projects ten times easier!